# Need Required Active Directory Ports for Isolated Environment

Tags: active-directory, firewall

We have a 100% isolated environment that needs to communicate with our AD infrastructure outside the isolated environment. I need to know all the ports and whether they're incoming or outgoing. These are the ports I've gathered so far. Can anyone help adding any that might be missing and the inbound / outbound direction. Thanks so much! (These are separated via physical firewall).

- TCP 135 : MS-RPC
- TCP 1025 & 1026 : AD Login & replication
- TCP 389 : LDAP
- TCP & UDP 53 : DNS
- TCP 445 : SMB , Microsoft-ds
- TCP 139 : SMB
- UDP 137 & 138 : NetBIOS related
- UDP 88 : Kerberos v5
- TCP 636: Secure LDAP
- TCP 3269: Secure LDAP

Comment: This should help https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd772723(v=ws.10).aspx and http://blogs.msmvps.com/acefekay/2011/11/01/active-directory-firewall-ports-let-s-try-to-make-this-simple/

Comment: Any indication if these ports need to be bi-directional, or how can I convince our networking team to open them? They always want to know inbound or outbound?

Answer (score 2):

This is the document you are looking for: [Active Directory and Active Directory Domain Services Port Requirements](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd772723%28v=ws.10%29.aspx)

> ## Default dynamic port range
>
> In a domain that consists of Windows Server® 2003–based domain
>   controllers, the default dynamic port range is 1025 through 5000.
>   Windows Server 2008 R2 and Windows Server 2008, in compliance with
>   Internet Assigned Numbers Authority (IANA) recommendations, increased
>   the dynamic port range for connections. The new default start port is
>   49152, and the new default end port is 65535. Therefore, you must
>   increase the remote procedure call (RPC) port range in your firewalls.
>   If you have a mixed domain environment that includes a Windows Server
>   2008 R2 and Windows Server 2008 server and Windows Server 2003, allow
>   traffic through ports 1025 through 5000 and 49152 through 65535.
>
> When you see **“TCP Dynamic”** in the Protocol and Port column in the
>   following table, it refers to ports 1025 through 5000, the default
>   port range for Windows Server 2003, and **ports 49152 through 65535, the
>   default port range beginning with Windows Server 2008.**

.

> ## Communication to Domain Controllers
>
> The following table lists the port requirements for establishing DC to
>   DC communication in all versions of Windows Sever beginning with
>   Windows Server 2003.
>
> Additional ports are required for [communication between a read-only
>   domain controller (RODC) and a writeable
>   DC](https://technet.microsoft.com/library/dd728028(ws.10).aspx).
>
> **Protocol and Port:** TCP and UDP 389
>   **AD and AD DS Usage:** Directory, Replication, User and Computer Authentication, Group Policy, Trusts
>   **Type of Traffic:** LDAP
>
> **Protocol and Port:** TCP 636
>   **AD and AD DS Usage:** Directory, Replication, User and Computer Authentication, Group Policy, Trusts
>   **Type of Traffic:** LDAP SSL
>
> **Protocol and Port:** TCP 3268
>   **AD and AD DS Usage:** Directory, Replication, User and Computer Authentication, Group Policy, Trusts
>   **Type of Traffic:** LDAP GC
>
> **Protocol and Port:** TCP 3269
>   **AD and AD DS Usage:** Directory, Replication, User and Computer Authentication, Group Policy, Trusts
>   **Type of Traffic:** LDAP GC SSL
>
> **Protocol and Port:** TCP and UDP 88
>   **AD and AD DS Usage:** User and Computer Authentication, Forest Level Trusts
>   **Type of Traffic:** Kerberos
>
> **Protocol and Port:** TCP and UDP 53
>   **AD and AD DS Usage:** User and Computer Authentication, Name Resolution, Trusts
>   **Type of Traffic:** DNS
>
> **Protocol and Port:** TCP and UDP 445
>   **AD and AD DS Usage:** Replication, User and Computer Authentication, Group Policy, Trusts
>   **Type of Traffic:** SMB,CIFS,SMB2, DFSN, LSARPC, NbtSS, NetLogonR, SamR, SrvSvc
>
> **Protocol and Port:** TCP 25
>   **AD and AD DS Usage:** Replication
>   **Type of Traffic:** SMTP
>
> **Protocol and Port:** TCP 135
>   **AD and AD DS Usage:** Replication
>   **Type of Traffic:** RPC, EPM
>
> **Protocol and Port:** TCP Dynamic
>   **AD and AD DS Usage:** Replication, User and Computer Authentication, Group Policy, Trusts
>   **Type of Traffic:** RPC, DCOM, EPM, DRSUAPI, NetLogonR, SamR, FRS
>
> **Protocol and Port:** TCP 5722
>   **AD and AD DS Usage:** File Replication
>   **Type of Traffic:** RPC, DFSR (SYSVOL)
>
> **Protocol and Port:** UDP 123
>   **AD and AD DS Usage:** Windows Time, Trusts
>   **Type of Traffic:** Windows Time
>
> **Protocol and Port:** TCP and UDP 464
>   **AD and AD DS Usage:** Replication, User and Computer Authentication, Trusts
>   **Type of Traffic:** Kerberos change/set password
>
> **Protocol and Port:** UDP Dynamic
>   **AD and AD DS Usage:** Group Policy
>   **Type of Traffic:** DCOM, RPC, EPM
>
> **Protocol and Port:** UDP 138
>   **AD and AD DS Usage:** DFS, Group Policy
>   **Type of Traffic:** DFSN, NetLogon, NetBIOS Datagram Service
>
> **Protocol and Port:** TCP 9389
>   **AD and AD DS Usage:** AD DS Web Services
>   **Type of Traffic:** SOAP
>
> **Protocol and Port:** UDP 67 and UDP 2535
>   **AD and AD DS Usage:** DHCP (DHCP is not a core AD DS service but it is often present in many AD DS deployments.)
>   **Type of Traffic:** DHCP, MADCAP
>
> **Protocol and Port:** UDP 137
>   **AD and AD DS Usage:** User and Computer Authentication,
>   **Type of Traffic:** NetLogon, NetBIOS Name Resolution
>
> **Protocol and Port:** TCP 139
>   **AD and AD DS Usage:** User and Computer Authentication, Replication
>   **Type of Traffic:** DFSN, NetBIOS Session Service, NetLogon

Comment: how can i tell if these ports need to be inbound or outbound? sorry if I'm not following.

Comment: The firewall guys should know what to do when you send them the article, or they probably look for ways of avoiding to change anything... But packets to those ports must be accepted. The sending host almost always uses a random source port to send data to a destination port.

Comment: In my case, they don't want to do anything. They want to know exactly what needs to be inbound and outbound and make my life miserable.

Comment: I just told you what is inbound and outbound. If you expect me to got through the list for you and give you a full explanation on every item, then you expect to much.

Comment: If you did tell me what was inbound or outbound I don't follow. If you could give me an example, that would be helpful. I have an environment that is currently in an isolated bubble completely blocked with no ports allowed. We need to communicate with AD outside the bubble, so our network admins wants to know the exact ports we need and if they need to be outbound from the bubble, bi-directional, or inbound to the bubble. I really don't think I'm expecting too much, that's why I came here for help.